# Update database file by downloading file from server(url)-android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How to save database file download from server in `/data/data/com.package.name/databases/file.db` path(update current database by deleting and replacing with new database--not to update app).

I had successfully downloaded file and saved it in `/data/data/com.package.name/files` .but then it does not get save to given path properly (permission problem)
firstly it shows correct size then try to pull file out to see the database it is empty and try to run app further it closes giving error table can not be found and file size decreases containing android_metadata table only.

I had successfully downloaded file and saved it in sdcard but it show error while reading file ---contains path separator

since i don't want to access database from sdcard.
i have split database file to 1mb each (3mb one file to three files).

Answer (score 1):

android does not allow to access it root path . so it wont allow you to save databse there. you can save database to sd card and then access it . or if you dont want to save it to sd card then create database yourself and then populate with records that you get from server.

Comment: i have saved to path, it shows correct file size but try to access or pull file, database file is empty

Comment: are you using emulator.?

Comment: i guess emulator should not give error but device will definitely give you error , because device is not rooted.